# How to return specific variable by passed variable name flutter?

Tags: flutter, variables, variable-names

I have levels screen and I want when I press on level 1 for example I want to get the list of level 1
is there a way to get it without using if or switch just like by passing the name of the list then return the list that I passed its name or something like that

Thanks

```
List<Map<String, Object>> question(var s)
{
 _1 = const [
    {
    'question':
    'In which month does the German festival of Oktoberfest mostly take place?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'January', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'October', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'September', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'Who composed the music for Sonic the Hedgehog 3?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Britney Spears', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Timbaland', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Michael Jackson', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'In Georgia (the state), it’s illegal to eat what with a fork?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Hamburgers', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Fried chicken', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'Pizza', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
 
];
 return s;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.. The method question will fetch the item in the index you pass. If you pass 0 it will fetch the first map from the list and return it..

```
import "dart:async";




void main() {
  List<Map<String, Object>> singleObject = question(0);
  
  print(singleObject[0]['question']);
  print(singleObject[0]['answers']);
}


List<Map<String, Object>> question(int s)
{
 List<Map<String, Object>> _1 = const [
    {
    'question':
    'In which month does the German festival of Oktoberfest mostly take place?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'January', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'October', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'September', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'Who composed the music for Sonic the Hedgehog 3?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Britney Spears', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Timbaland', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Michael Jackson', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'In Georgia (the state), it’s illegal to eat what with a fork?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Hamburgers', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Fried chicken', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'Pizza', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
 
];
  List<Map<String, Object>> _2 = const [
    {
    'question':
    'In which month does the German festival of Oktoberfest mostly take place?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'January', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'October', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'September', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'Who composed the music for Sonic the Hedgehog 3?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Britney Spears', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Timbaland', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Michael Jackson', 'score': true},
    ],
  },
  {
    'question': 'In Georgia (the state), it’s illegal to eat what with a fork?',
    'answers': [
      {'answerText': 'Hamburgers', 'score': false},
      {'answerText': 'Fried chicken', 'score': true},
      {'answerText': 'Pizza', 'score': false},
    ],
  },
 
];
  
  List allQuestions = [_1,_2];
 return allQuestions[s];
}
```

Comment: it seems like you misunderstand my question 
I don't want to return the question I want to return the whole list "_1"

Comment: So just return _1 instead of _1[s]

Comment: for example I have 10 levels 
when the user choose level 5 it will return _5
so I want a way to return the list of chosen level without use if return for every level

Answer (score 0):

You can use maps.
The key of the map will be the level name, and the value will be the list of questions.

For Example:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> leveledQuestionsMap = {
   "L1" : [firstLevelQuestions],
   "L2" : [secondLevelQuestions],
   "L3" : [thirdLevelQuestions],
}
```

and then make a function that takes level and returns the values from the map:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> bringQuestionOfLevel(String level){
   return leveledQuestionsMap[level];
}
```

Comment: thanks
but when I use the function to get the list 
it gives me an error
=======
this is some of my code 

  List<List<Map<String, Object>>> _questions = Q().bringQuestionOfLevel(e) ;
-----
                    _questions[_questionIndex]['question'],

Comment: lib/home.dart:125:48: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
                    _questions[_questionIndex]['question'],
                                               ^

Comment: lib/home.dart:125:48: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
                    _questions[_questionIndex]['question'],
                                               ^
lib/home.dart:125:47: Error: The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
                    _questions[_questionIndex]['question'],
                                              ^

Comment: lib/home.dart:135:46: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
              ...(_questions[_questionIndex]['answers']
                                             ^

Comment: Share the updated code in the question above.